# Create a csv file from Hive Table in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

can someone suggest on how to create a delimited file (comma or pipe) with headers (column names) from a Hive table using Nifi

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **SelectHiveQL** processor

- Configure/use the **HiveController service**
- Keep your **Select Query**,select the **output format as CSV and header to true** 
  Then processor outputs the results of Select Query in CSV format.

**Configs:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response...I'll give it a try and revert!